# getting the date from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `jQuery`'s `datepicker` in other to get some dates from the user. I defined the form was following:

```
<form id="myform" action="/graphs/get_builds" method="post">
   Start: <input type="text" id="start" />
   End:   <input type="text" id="end" />
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

on the `JS` side, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {
        'start': $('#start').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
                return $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            }
        });
    };
    console.log(data);
    // bind 'myform' and provide a simple callback function
    $('#myform').ajaxForm(function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    });

});
```

I know the definition on the `data` value it's not right, but how could I get the value of `start` and `end` in other to pass that to a back to the `ajaxForm`. I need the value of both `start` and `end`. On the server side I have a method waiting for both the `start` and `end` dates so I could perform some operations. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the input value (set by datepicker).
To get by server side you need to set 'name' property first.

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm( function() {
    var start_data = $("#start").val();
    var end_data = $("#end").val();

    console.log(start_data);
    console.log(end_data);

    console.log("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Not quite but close! Thx

Answer (score 0):

The "start" and "end" are already in the form. All you have to do is submit it to the server via ajaxSubmit.

```
var options = {
  target: '/graphs/get_builds' // the target server side page
};

$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // submit the form via ajax
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

  return false;
});
```